# Strange terminal behaviour over SSH from WSL to Ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I connect to a Ubuntu server from my Windows machine, inside of of Ubuntu installed in Windows Subsystem for Linux the terminal is acting very strangely.

This might sound crazy but whenever try to edit a line which contains dash (-) or (+) or similar special characters then the terminal seems to be messed up and it does not insert the new text correctly.

Let me show you:

[image]

I have no idea what to do about it but it is totally driving me crazy.

Some more details.

**Local machine**:

```
$echo "$PS1"
\[\033]0;:/home/said\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\] \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]\[\033[0m\]\n$

$locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**Remote machine**:

```
: echo "$PS1"
\[\033[38;5;2m\]\h\[\]\[\033[38;5;29m\] \[\]\[\033[38;5;11m\]\w\[\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]\n: \[\]

: locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

This happens when I go WSL (Ubuntu 16.04) -> SSH -> (Ubuntu 16.04) (tried against two different remove Ubuntu hosts) but not when I go for example from my Mac over SSH to the same server.

Comment: Add the output of `echo "$PS1"`, please.

Comment: muru: I added the result of that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was related to using `TERM=xterm-color` on the remote host. Changing it to `TERM=xterm-256color` mitigates the problem.

It was reported and investigated on [Microsoft/console GitHub Issue #139](https://github.com/Microsoft/console/issues/139).